# How can I create a better mysql query with php than this one

Tags: php, mysql

First of all I am currently trying to learn php and I thought I would build a basic maintenance management app to better grasp everything I see in tutorials, and I hit a roadblock.

This here is my code: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/b8eu-q1x9

It's ugly, it's big and I do not know how I can make it better.

I am getting information from an equipment table and from an ops table and I want to put them in the clients table. The reason the file above is so cluttered is that I wanted for each client to have at most 25 equipments and for each equipment I wanted to be able to add at most 35 operations. And since I couldn't find a good tutorial on how many-to-many mysql relashionships are done with php, the code above resulted.

So, can anyone help me ? Is there a way to write the code I have above to not be so big ?

Comment: This is totally wrong. You have to normalize your tables to equipment table, operations table and equipment_operation table. Since i'm totally unaware about your full application; consider this as a suggestion and do some research on this.

Comment: First thing to learn is to use meaningless variable names like $eq_2_op_32

Comment: @TismonVarghese I know it's wrong, and I managed to find out myself that I need an equipment_operation table but I can't figure out how to make php write data and retrieve data from that table. As for how the tables look, well, they are similar to what you posted below. And because I couldn't figure that one out I came up with the solution above

Comment: @e4c5 I am a beginner, thus I am in the process of learning all of this stuff and you basically said " this is wrong, figure something else out ". Sorry but that does not help me at all.

Comment: Welcome to the world of programming. Sorry if it doesn't help you. But at the same time it would have been a simple matter to google for meaningful variable names.

Comment: @e4c5 Look, it's really hard to make out the tone of a conversation in writing, but I just meant I can't see how it would help me with this problem. I did google meaningful variable names and I will look into it further but so far I can't really see the problem, the variable would translate as operation 32 for equipment 1.

Answer (score 0):

Please find a rough idea on tables below. Its not complete; you have to work on and develop a better version

```
Equipments
----------
equipemnt_id
equipemnt_name

Operations
----------
operations_id
operation_name

Clients
-------
client_id
client_name
... and the necessary fields

Equipment_operations
--------------------
eq_op_id
client_id
equipemnt_id
operations_id
```